# "Socket error: could not connect to host" exception in php-amqp

Tags: php, rabbitmq, php-amqp

I have written a function which checks if rabbitmq is running.

```
function getBrokerStatus()
{
    log_message("info", "Checking if broker is running....");
    try {
        $amqpConnection = new AMQPConnection();
        $amqpConnection->setLogin("guest");
        $amqpConnection->setPassword("guest");
        $amqpConnection->setVhost("/");
        $amqpConnection->connect();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        log_message("info", "Exception: " . $e->getMessage());
        return false;
    }

    if (!$amqpConnection->isConnected()) {
        log_message("info", "Cannot connect to the broker! It might not be running");
        return false;
    }
    $amqpConnection->disconnect();
    return true;
}
```

My code catches this exception. I see below in logs -

```
Exception: Socket error: could not connect to host.
```

But my rabbitmq server is running then why am I getting this exception? I am using `v3.1.1` of rabbitmq-server.

Comment: Since your code doesn't state either the broker's host or the host the status checker is trying to make a connection to, it's hard to judge.

Comment: If it helps, when I print `new AMQPConnection()` instance I get - `AMQPConnection Object
(
    [login] => guest
    [password] => guest
    [host] => localhost
    [vhost] => /
    [port] => 5672
    [read_timeout] => 0
    [write_timeout] => 0
)
`

Comment: It's strange. Obviously, the connection attempt to the same host:port should result the same. My best guess is that there must be some difference. That's not much to say, but that's how I'd go about it. To find it.

Comment: Please, specify platform versions. Do you have access to RabbitMQ management panel?

Comment: I am using `v3.1.1` of rabbitmq-server. I think 'http://localhost:5672` will take me to RabbitMQ management panel. But I am not able to access it. I mean that url is not found

Comment: You have to enable the management panel. Also make sure you've started RabbitMQ.

Comment: Hi I have enabled it using `sudo rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management` and I can see it at `http://localhost:15672`. But still I am getting the same error.

Comment: I took advice from @asksolem and used `$amqpConnection->setHost("127.0.0.1");` It is working now. But I don't know what's the issue with `localhost`

Answer (score 0):

if you cannot ping your localhost on your machine, it must be you didn't setup your hosts file.
Edit it in /etc/hosts